# How can I fix pod install error in react-native?

Tags: react-native

When I run `pod install` in my react-native project I get this **error** -

```html
!] /usr/bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="arm64"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

# Manually disable gflags include to fix issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28446
sed -i '' 's/\@ac_cv_have_libgflags\@/0/' src/glog/logging.h.in
sed -i '' 's/HAVE_LIB_GFLAGS/HAVE_LIB_GFLAGS_DISABLED/' src/config.h.in

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

/usr/bin/bash: line 25: xcrun: command not found
/usr/bin/bash: line 25: xcrun: command not found
sed: can't read s/\@ac_cv_have_libgflags\@/0/: No such file or directory
```

My **podfile**

```html
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'NewApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target 'NewApp' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  # post_install do |installer|
  #   react_native_post_install(installer)
  #   __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  # end
end
```

My **package.json**

```html
{
  "name": "NewApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.67.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.19.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.69.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My **System**

I am using a Linux system.

```
Linux user 5.16.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 5.16.7-2kali1 (2022-02-10) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Versions**

```
node: v16.14.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: "0.67.3"
react: "17.0.2",
```

How can I solve this error? I want to develop only android apps. But when I run `react-native start` I get this **error**-

> Error: react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null. To fix this issue try these steps:
> • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then clean, rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.

Can I skip the ios part for now and build only android apps or how can I solve the pod install error? Please help!

Answer (score 7):

In my case the installed version of sed was the problem. React Native assumes default sed installation on macos, which is able to process the following expression:

```
sed -i '' 's/\@ac_cv_have_libgflags\@/0/' src/glog/logging.h.in
```

On my CI system I installed gnu-sed, which led to the mentioned error.

Check your system and ensure `sed` points to default macos installation (`/usr/bin/sed`). If you require gnu-sed for other scripts (in my case, I required gnu-sed specific syntaxt in a versioning script), you can install it side by side with brew:

`brew install gnu-sed`

You can call gnu-sed with `gsed`.

HTH

Comment: Holy ****! This was actually the same problem I faced! I uninstalled gnu-sed `brew uninstall gnu-sed` and now it works.

Comment: For reasons I could not uninstall/rename gnu-sed and even when editing PATH I couldn't get it working (it still used gnu-sed), so I went the ugly way edited `node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh` and removed the empty quotes (`''`)  from the two `sed -i '' [some garbage]` which is the equivalent syntax for gnu-sed. Very much an unstable workaround, so not recommended, but if nothing else works there you are...

Comment: This issue is also fixed in RN0.70.0-rc3 and both sed versions are supported: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/4a7e4b9ca6ef4fb52611b6c3cb788f624d1f81a4